# Laravel schedule does not run automatically

Tags: laravel

I have laravel schedule setup as below

1. Create command and name its.

   ```
   class BackupDatabase extends Command{
    protected $signature = 'command:backupdatabase';
   ```
2. Register command in kernel.php

   ```
   protected $commands = [
   Commands\BackupDatabase::class
   ```
3. Setup handle

   ```
   Artisan::call('backup:run',['--only-db'=>true]);
   $output = Artisan::output();
   ```
4. Add to schedule

   ```
   $schedule->command('command:backupdatabase')->everyMinute();
   ```

Nothing happen on this schedule. Btw, I already tried 'php artisan command:backupdatabase' in terminal and function working perfectly. I'm not sure what I'am doing wrong, Thanks for all advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up the crontab

```html
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Laravel scheduled tasks work becouse the system is scheduled to execute the laravel command "schedule:run" that itself take care of executing the laravel scheduled command on the right time.

Comment: Thanks actually, This is my action 1. run 'crontab -e' 2. Insert '* * * * * php /var/www/html/srp && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1' and save. Then bang, work great.